# cURL and Google Analytics

Tags: php, curl, laravel-5

I am using laravel-gamp (https://github.com/irazasyed/laravel-gamp) to track events in my Laravel 5.2 REST server. However if I set sending method to sync I always get this error (I am using SSL):

> cURL error 7: Failed to connect to ssl.google-analytics.com port 443:
> Connection refused (see
> http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/libcurl-errors.html)

I am running Laravel on a Ubuntu VM with cURL updated to the latest version.

How can I fix this error?
Thanks

Comment: Top of my head, I recall using following somewhere in my code. Add CURL_IPRESOLVE_V4 option in your curl request.

    `curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_IPRESOLVE, CURL_IPRESOLVE_V4);
`
I am not sure where you can put this in gamp.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply it was Ubuntu iptables blocking outgoing connections for port 443